# Asterisk Event to listen to for Transferred call

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

I'm building an application that listens to the Asterisk AMI to see when a user gets a call or makes a call out. I have got the events for when a user gets a call and when they make a call out. But what event do I listen for when a call gets transferred to a user or the user picks up the call with a feature code? The events that I am using now are AgentCalled and Newchannel. I would appreciate any advice on this topic. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For asterisk 1.8 you have check

```
Transfer
Masquerade
Bridge
Hangup
```

events.
For 11+ bridge replaced by "Link" event.

Just do transfer and dump all events you got, you will see needed events for your asterisk version.  There are more then one method of transfer, events will be different.

Comment: The bridge event works great with the bridgestate equalling Link or Unlink